# Need help creating tags for 3D Robotics APIs

Tags: support, tags

At 3D Robotics, we released a set of API's to build apps for drones last week and we want to use Stack Overflow to direct support questions. We would like to have some tags created since no one on the immediate team has more rep than 1500.

**Tags:**

- **dronekit-python**: to be used with our Python library
- **dronekit-cloud**: everything related to our cloud services goes here
- **dronekit-android**: if you want to build an android app using this api you might need support and our devs will be constantly lurking StackOverflow
  to help people
- **dronekit**: General architectural or setup questions will go here, sometimes you don't know how to tag a question this is the generic
  tag for the brand.

More info on the release of DroneKit: http://dronekit.io/
Some media reactions:

- Engadget:
  http://www.engadget.com/2015/03/26/create-apps-drones-dronekit/ Tech
  Crunch:
  http://techcrunch.com/2015/03/26/3d-robotics-launches-dronekit-its-api-for-building-drone-apps/
  3D Robotics:
  http://3drobotics.com/2015/03/3dr-announces-dronekit-open-platform-creating-drone-apps/
  Programmable Web:
  http://www.programmableweb.com/news/3dr-releases-dronekit-sdk-and-api-building-drone-apps/2015/04/02

I believe these tags will help the community and help further grow commercial adoption of Drones.

Questions:

- Python: [How to use dronekit with SITL vagrant VM from dev Wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387303/how-to-use-dronekit-with-sitl-vagrant-vm-from-dev-wiki)
- Cloud: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29436082/what-is-the-api-key-spec-for-dronekit-cloud

Comment: _"since no one on the immediate team has more rep than 1500"_ :( gain rep folks!

Comment: You need to have questions to which these tags would apply for the tags to be created.

Comment: We are planning on gaining lots of rep once we can offer support through StackOverflow, in the meantime you might be able to help us :)

Comment: @Servy Thanks, I'll update my question with links to those questions.

Comment: @rroche _"once we can offer support through StackOverflow"_ I'm not sure that outsourcing your support site to SO is a really good idea. You might well install your own clone of the engine to one of your servers, to support the brilliant FAQ format, if that's what you're actually after. Otherwise I'd suspect any appearance here as spamming.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, we think this is the right platform for our product.

Comment: Also read: [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745)

Comment: @Deduplicator Thanks, we are not expecting the StackOverflow community to do the "Support", our product is open source and we want to direct people to the right place to ask questions, we are dedicating resources to monitor and answer those questions, we want to help the community grow.

Comment: Good to hear. You might want to properly tag 5 or so questions with each of the new tags now (don't mis-tag and don't seed question, both will backfire), and also provide a tag-wiki for each (probably with cross-linking). Beware of market-speak there, just describe what it's for and provide links to the official documentation. There is special guidance for proper tag-wikis...

Comment: As an FYI, you will have someone working there soon who has sufficient reputation to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/users/23113/schwa . Tell Jon I said hello.

Comment: Just to let you know the dronkit-android tag went away since there were no questions tagged with it.  Let me know if you get a question it should be on, and I'll tag it so.

Comment: @LanceRoberts this is the android question thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527513/is-there-a-mavlink-mission-commands-list-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done, I added them to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387303/how-to-use-dronekit-with-sitl-vagrant-vm-from-dev-wiki) and then removed the 'cloud' and 'android' variants.  You'll want to have them applied to some questions soon to keep them active.

Comment: Thanks for your help, we want to help the community and we believe this is the right way to do it.